# Determine, with proof, whether the following are the same subgroups of Z^2: < (4,3), (2,5) > and < (6, 7) , (8, 1) >?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It's a very simple question I just don't understand why I don't get it.

Comment: I would guess that you have been taught some method for solving problems like this. The general method is to put the matrices into Hermite Normal Form.

Comment: Computing the area of the lattice cells would be one way to start.

Comment: That works in this example, because the areas are different, but equal areas would not necessarily imply that the subgroups were equal.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose $H=\langle (4,3), (2,5) \rangle = \langle (6, 7) , (8, 1) \rangle=H'$. We note that $(6,7)=a(4,3)+b(2,5)$ for some integers $a,b$ because $(6,7)\in H'$ and so then we must also have $(6,7)\in H$. This gives us the simultaneous equations $$6=4a+2b\\7=3a+5b.$$

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental parallelograms of the first lattice have area $\bigl|(4,3)\wedge(2,5)\bigr|=14$ whereas the fundamental parallelograms of  the second group have area $\bigl|(6,7)\wedge(8,1)\bigr|=50$. It follows that the two groups cannot be the same.